# .start() does not start the process and causes the program to crash

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

in the code posted below, i am subclassing Process. And as stated in some tutorials, .start must be called to start the worked process.
the problem I am facing, is that i can not invoke the .start() method because it causes the app to crash and generate the error message posted below. instead, i invoke .run() method.
please let me know why i can not use .start() and whey it generates that error message ans how to fix it so i can use .start()

**Note**: the code posted below is in a webservice

**error msg**:

```
File "C:\Python310\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 100, in _check_closed
    if self._closed:
AttributeError: 'KeyGridCellsProcessing' object has no attribute '_closed'
```

**code**:

```
class KeyGridCellsProcessing(Process):

    @staticmethod
    def newInstance(pNameSuffix,row,col,_pixelsValuesSatisfyThresholdInWindowedSegment,pixelsValuesSatisfyThresholdInTIFFImageDatasetCnt):
        keyGridCellsProcessing = KeyGridCellsProcessing(pNameSuffix,row,col,_pixelsValuesSatisfyThresholdInWindowedSegment,pixelsValuesSatisfyThresholdInTIFFImageDatasetCnt)
        KeyGridCellsProcessing.processesCollector.append(KeyGridCellsProcessing)
        return keyGridCellsProcessing
    
    @staticmethod
    def setDatasetElevationsTIFFInEPSG25832(datasetElevationsTIFFInEPSG25832):
        KeyGridCellsProcessing.datasetElevationsTIFFInEPSG25832 = datasetElevationsTIFFInEPSG25832
    
    @staticmethod
    def setNDVIsTIFFWindowedSegmentContentsInEPSG25832(NDVIsTIFFWindowedSegmentContentsInEPSG25832):
        KeyGridCellsProcessing.NDVIsTIFFWindowedSegmentContentsInEPSG25832 = NDVIsTIFFWindowedSegmentContentsInEPSG25832
        
    @staticmethod
    def setMainTIFFImageDatasetContents(mainTIFFImageDatasetContents):
        KeyGridCellsProcessing.mainTIFFImageDatasetContents = mainTIFFImageDatasetContents
    
    @staticmethod
    def waitForProcessToFinish():
        for p in KeyGridCellsProcessing.processesCollector:
            p.join()  
            # logger.debug(f"process:{p}")
        # exit()
            
    def __init__(self,pNameSuffix,row,col,_pixelsValuesSatisfyThresholdInWindowedSegment,pixelsValuesSatisfyThresholdInTIFFImageDatasetCnt):
        # self.queue = queue
        self.pNameSuffix = pNameSuffix
        self.row = row
        self.col = col
        self._pixelsValuesSatisfyThresholdInWindowedSegment = _pixelsValuesSatisfyThresholdInWindowedSegment
        self.pixelsValuesSatisfyThresholdInTIFFImageDatasetCnt = pixelsValuesSatisfyThresholdInTIFFImageDatasetCnt
        self.fourCornersOfKeyWindowInEPSG4326 = []
        
    def run(self):
        runStartTime = time.time()
        #logic
        ...
        ...
        runEndTime = time.time() - runStartTime
        KeyGridCellsProcessing.runMethodForKeyGridCellsExecutionTimeAccumulator+=runEndTime
    
    @staticmethod
    def enqueue():
        KeyGridCellsProcessing.keyGridCellsQueue.put([KeyGridCellsProcessing.NDVIsPer10mX10mForKeyWindow,
                                ......,
                                ......,
                                ......,
                                ......,
                                ......,
                                ], block=True, timeout=None)
    @staticmethod
    def dequeue():
        deqeueStartTime = time.time()
        item = KeyGridCellsProcessing.keyGridCellsQueue.get(block=True, timeout=None)
        KeyGridCellsProcessing.executionTimeOfDequeueProcess = time.time() - deqeueStartTime
        return item
    
    
    @staticmethod
    def shutdownQueue():
        KeyGridCellsProcessing.keyGridCellsQueue.close()
        KeyGridCellsProcessing.keyGridCellsQueue.join_thread()

    def startProcessing(self):
        #self.start()#<=========== causes the app to crash
        self.run()  #works
```

Comment: Please, provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

`start()` first action is to call `self._check_closed()` in `BaseProcess` (base class for `Process`)

```
def _check_closed(self):
    if self._closed:
        raise ValueError("process object is closed")
```

`self._closed` is initialized in `BaseProcess` `__init__`, but since you don't have `super().__init__()` in your class it's never initialized. Adding it should solve the issue

```
class KeyGridCellsProcessing(Process):
    def __init__(self, ...):
        super().__init__()
        ...
```